# Are any archive file formats natively supported in IOS?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5

Generating a UIWebView with on-board resources is easy enough with the following code.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

However, what I need to do is move one step past simply having pre-generated data on the device, to actually downloading the data from a server to store locally.  A lot of that I can handle myself with a reasonable degree of ease, but the question becomes:  'what archive formats does IOS natively support?'

I know there are add-ons that let me support ZIP or PKZip, but if possible it would be preferable to restrict to Apple's built-in tools.

Comment: BTW, as a note to anyone who drops by, I phrased my question very deliberately.  Not 'what native support is available', but rather 'is there native support available' (with the implied 'that I missed while going through the SDK independently).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we interpret "archive" generously, as a way to store heterogeneous data in a single file without necessarily compressing it, then you could consider property lists and SQLite databases as archive formats.  And, yes, the word "archive" is sometimes used that way, as in .tar format.

Comment: I... never thought of it that way.  While I meant 'archive' as in a way to store a series of files while retaining directory structure (e. g. zip and rar), I suppose your's is a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Apparently no native archive format support exists.